# Gatsby only passing on checkbox value to Netlify forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have an array of checkboxes and I want to pass which checboxes have been selected to Netlify forms.

Right now only one of the values is passed, instead I want them all to be passed and formatted nicely (a comma in between).

My checkbox looks like this, it loops through data fetched from an array from a headless CMS and display all the checkboxes as it should

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Inquery type</legend>
    {formData.radioButtons.map((node, index) => (
      <>
        <p>
          <label key={index}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={("inqueryType", index)}
              name="inqueryType"
              ref={register()}
              value={node}
              onChange={handleChange}
              key={(node, "checbox")}
            />
            {node}
          </label>
        </p>
      </>
    ))}
  </fieldset>
```

My handleChange function looks like this

```
  const handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.type === "checkbox" && !e.target.checked) {
      setState(prev => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))
    } else {
      setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
  }
```

I suspect that my error is in my handleChange method, but I have been unable to figure out why it only stores one value instead of all of them. Any ideas?

My onSubmit looks like this

```
const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch("/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: encode({
        "form-name": "contactGudcForm",
        ...state,
      }),
    })
      .then(response => {
        setFeedbackMsg(`Thanks for reaching out. I'll get back to you soon.`)
        reset()
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setFeedbackMsg(
          "Oops, something went wrong. The form could not be submitted."
        )
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

and my encude function, shamlessly stolen from StackOverflow looks like this

```
function encode(data) {
  return Object.keys(data)
    .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
    .join("&")
}
```

This is a Gatsby project deploying to Netlify using standard Netlify forms

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your checkboxes share the same `name` attribute (`inqueryType` in your example), therefore they will overwrite eachother here:

```js
const handleChange = e => {
  // ...
  setState(prev => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))
  // ...
}
```

What happens is that you're adding the form data to state using the inputs' `name` as the key. Since your checkboxes don't have a unique `name`, it kind of does this:

```js
const state = {}

// push the value of the first checkbox
state["inqueryType"] = "value 1"

// push the value of the second checkbox
state["inqueryType"] = "value 2"

// "value 1" is gone :(
```

Make sure that your keys are unique, and you should be fine!

**Edit**: as mentioned in the comments, you can format the data in any shape you like, as long as you don't overwrite it. If you want a stringified array of values for your group of checkboxes, you could do something like this:

```js
const handleChange = e => {
  if (e.target.name === "inqueryType") {
    const inqueryType = [...state.inqueryType, e.target.value]
    setState({ ...state, inqueryType: JSON.stringify(inqueryType) })
  }
  else {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
}
```

Of course there might be better solutions for your particular use case - this part is up to you :)

Comment: I tried that approach earlier, while it works the output is less than ideal 
0 General inquiry

1

2 Project work


Ideally I would get them in a list with commas, using my the "old" way I showed in the original post I would get only one value, console shows all the values as one array each value. then I get the correct heading as well. 

I changed name to "node" :)

Comment: Netlify forums recommend the same name for all the radio buttons too 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61172169/gatsby-only-passing-on-checkbox-value-to-netlify-forms

Comment: As long as you don't overwrite data, the way you shape it is pretty much up to you. If you want an array of values for `inqueryType`, you can simply add any values for the `inqueryType` field to an array - I've edited my answer with an example of what I mean :)

Comment: Radio buttons is a different story - you *want* a single value to be passed. In contrast, you can check multiple checkboxes in a group. (PS. I think the link in your comment doesn't point to the right place)

Comment: Thank you for updating your example, I implented your code but now I'm back to only one of the array elements showing up in Netlify, in my console the array elements still show up as a nested array instead of just one value with comma in between.

Comment: Sounds that you don't need an array but a string, then. Try `JSON.stringify()` (updating the example again)

Comment: Thanks for you update again, changing to your updated code how ever yielded the same result, only one value is passed to Netlify forms. I would add a screenshot but they are not supported in comments